# Wrong mehods are called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an asp.net mvc4 page in which there is one form and two grids, but my problem is that the grids are firing the wrong methods and I have no clue what is wrong.

My update method is calling the update method and other methods are firing wrong methods as well.

Can anyone figure this out?

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<SSTS.Models.StudentsViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              // columns.Bound(student => student.CustomerName);
              columns.Bound(student => student.SchoolYear).Width(160);


              columns.Bound(student => student.YearStart).Width(50);
              columns.Bound(student => student.YearEnd).Width(50);
                columns.Command(commands =>
              {
                  commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
                  commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items
              }).Title("Commands").Width(50);
          })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) // The "create" command adds new data items
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) // Use inline editing mode
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              dataSource.Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                {

                    model.Id(student => student.StudentNumber); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                //    model.Field(student => student.StudentNumber).Editable(false); // Make the studentID property not editable


                })
                .Create(create => create.Action("students_Create", "Student")) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
                .Read(read => read.Action("students_Read", "Student"))  // Action invoked when the grid needs data
                .Update(update => update.Action("students_Update", "Student"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("students_Destroy", "Student")) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
          )
              .Pageable()
%>
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid<SSTS.Models.StudentsViewModel>()
    .Name("grid2")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              // columns.Bound(student => student.CustomerName);
              columns.Bound(student => student.BoardingPoint);//.ClientTemplate("#=CustomerNames.CustomerName#").Width(160);

              columns.Bound(student => student.StudentNumber).ClientTemplate(
    "<a href='" +
        Url.Action("ViewStudent", "Home") +
        "/#= StudentNumber #'" +
    ">#= StudentNumber #</a>"
); ;


              columns.Bound(student => student.Description).Width(250);
              columns.Bound(student => student.NumberofSections).Width(250);
              columns.Bound(student => student.ContactNumber).Width(250);
                columns.Command(commands =>
              {
                  commands.Edit(); // The "edit" command will edit and update data items
                  commands.Destroy(); // The "destroy" command removes data items
              }).Title("Commands").Width(200);
          })
          .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) // The "create" command adds new data items
          .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) // Use inline editing mode
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
              dataSource.Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(student => student.StudentNumber); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model
                //    model.Field(student => student.StudentNumber).Editable(false); // Make the studentID property not editable

              //      model.Field(p => p.CustomerNames).DefaultValue(
               //         ViewData["defaultCategory"] as KendoGridAjaxEditing2.Models.CustomerNamesViewModel);


                })
                    .Create(create => create.Action("BoardingPoints_Create", "Student")) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
                    .Read(read => read.Action("BoardingPoints_Read", "Student"))  // Action invoked when the grid needs data
                    .Update(update => update.Action("BoardingPoints_Update", "Student"))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("BoardingPoints_Destroy", "Student")) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item
          )
          .Pageable()

%>


 public ActionResult students_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
              _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();


            return Json(StudentRepository.GetSchoolYear(_studNum).ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }



        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult students_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel students)
        {
            var results = new List<StudentsViewModel>();

            if (students != null )//&& ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                   _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();
                StudentRepository.InsertSchoolYear(students, _studNum);
                results.Add(students);

            }

            return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult students_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel students)
        {
            if (students != null)
            {

                _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();

                StudentRepository.UpdateSchoolYear(students);
                UpdateModel(students);




            }
            return Json(new[] { students }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult students_Destroy([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel product)
        {
            _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();

            StudentRepository.DeleteSchoolYear(product);



            return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        private void PopulateStudents()
        {
            var dataContext = new SSTSDBDataModelDataContext();
            var categories = dataContext.tblMasterStudents
                        .Select(c => new StudentsViewModel
                        {
                            StudentNumber = c.StudentNumber
                            // StudentNumber=categories
                            // StudentNumber=categories.
                        })
                        .OrderBy(e => e.StudentNumber);
            ViewData["students"] = categories;
            ViewData["defaultCategory"] = categories.First();
        }
        public JsonResult GetPrsoducts(string text)
        {
            var northwind = new SSTSDBDataModelDataContext();


            var products = northwind.tblMasterStudents.Select(product => new StudentsViewModel
            {
                StudentNumber = product.StudentNumber
            });

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                products = products.Where(p => p.StudentNumber.Contains(text));
            }

            return Json(products, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }



        public ActionResult BoardingPoints_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();


            return Json(StudentRepository.GetSBoardingPoint(_studNum).ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult BoardingPoints_Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel students)
        {
            var results = new List<StudentsViewModel>();

            if (students != null )
            {
                  _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();
                StudentRepository.InsertBoardingPoint(students, _studNum);
                results.Add(students);

            }

            return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult BoardingPoints_Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel students)
        {
            if (students != null )
            {
                _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();


                StudentRepository.UpdateBoardingPoint(students);
                UpdateModel(students);




            }
            return Json(new[] { students }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }

        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult BoardingPoints_Destroy([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentsViewModel product)
        {

            _studNum = HttpContext.Session["StudentNumber"].ToString();
            StudentRepository.DeleteBoardingPoint(product);



            return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
        }


        //  public tblMasterStudent _stud { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you expect to happen and what happens instead. "Wrong method" is not enough information.

Comment: when i am calling BoardingPoints_Update  then BoardingPoints_create method is calling similarly when i am calling read method then other method is calling  and the same thing is happening with my other grid

Comment: student_update calling student_ucreate method

Comment: can anyone help me out please

Answer (score 0):

One reason that the Kendo DataSource might call the create method instead of the update method is if it thinks the record is new.

It may think the record is new if the ID is null or 0. Make sure your `StudentNumber` specified here

```
model.Id(student => student.StudentNumber);
```

is not null or 0 when it is returned from `students_Read`.

Comment: yea it is not null nor 0 sometime it calls the correct method sometimes not sometime it calls the create method twice

Comment: When it calls the create method instead of update, see if it passed a correct StudentNumber, or if it is null or 0. Maybe there is a duplicate record in your DataSource, and one has a blank ID. You can write some javascript in the devtools console to get the datasource off the grid, loop over all the records, and see if `.isNew()` returns true for any of them.

Comment: can you please explain me bit more i am new in asp,net mvc and if you can give me some code that would be great